# Ansible: running from virtualenvwrapper with pip installation

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, openssh, ssh-agent, ansible

I'm trying to test ansible with a "pip" installation of ansible in a virtualenv of python managed by virtualenvwrapper. However, I am having problems to use the ssh-agent and the SSH keys:

```
(ansible)$ ansible all -m ping
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jtbpizac/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jtbpizac/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jtbpizac/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jtbpizac/.ssh/id_rsa':
Enter passphrase for key '/home/jtbpizac/.ssh/id_rsa':
```

However, I can use the ssh-agent from this shell to connect remotely through ssh without problems:

```
(ansible)$ ssh root@X.X.X.X
```

And the ssh-agent seems to be available from the shell I launch ansible:

```
(ansible)$ ssh-add -l
2048 SHA256:.. (RSA)
1024 SHA256:.. (DSA)
2048 SHA256:.. (RSA)
(ansible)$ ssh-agent -s
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-yE20HcbylzCJ/agent.14461; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=14462; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 14462;
```

Any idea? I am using Ubuntu 15.10. Thanks!

Comment: First run `ansible all -m ping -vvv` for more detailed info.

Comment: In the first example you are logging in as your user (-ping), in the second as root. It is not exactly the same login.

Comment: I finally got the problem. I needed to specify the user to connect through ssh. Sorry for the mesh: `ansible all -u root -m ping`. @RuiFRibeiro was right!

Comment: exactly. I do advise also to not connect as root and use sudo. I use ansible that way and it works pretty well. ssh disables root by default for very good reasons

Answer (score 0):

In the file ~/.ansible.cfg, locallly, add:

```
[defaults]
transport=ssh
```

Ansible by default uses paramiko( a Python ssh tool ).  The above will tell ansible to use your local ssh (openssh usually).

Comment: `paramiko` is not used by default in current versions of Ansible (since Ansible 1.3) - see [this doc section](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_getting_started.html#remote-connection-information).